# how can I Redirect all requests to https and non-www in one jump?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect all requests to https and non-www in one jump for main/ home page and other sub pages.
I am using the following htaccess. [source](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9770/38/how-to-use-htaccess-to-redirect-to-https-in-cpanel)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mytesting\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mytesting\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://www.mytesting.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I got the following redirection

[image]

I want like this:

```
http://mytesting.com          > https://mytesting.com
http://www.mytesting.com      > https://mytesting.com
http://mytesting.com/faq      > https://mytesting.com/faq
https://mytesting.com         > https://mytesting.com
http://www.mytesting.com      > https://mytesting.com
http://www.mytesting.com/faq  > https://mytesting.com/faq
https://mytesting.com/faq     > https://mytesting.com/faq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule for both redirects in one rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Here is the explanation of this rule:

- `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]`: if `HOST_NAME` starts with `www.`
- `[NC,OR]`: Ignore case match and `OR`s next condition
- `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`: `HTTPS` is not turned on
- `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]`: This condition will always match since `www.` is an optional match here. It is used to capture substring of `HTTP_HOST` without starting `www.` by using `(.+)` pattern in capture group #1 (to be back-referenced as `%1` later). Note that `(?:..)` is a non-capturing group.
- `RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]`: `^` will always match. This rule will redirect to `https://%1%{REQUEST_URI}` with `R=301` code. Where `%1` is back-reference of capture group #1 from `RewriteCond`, as mentioned above.