# how can I Redirect all requests to https and www in one jump with subpages

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all my WP sites to https and www.

searched a lot and tried many like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this works only half way, but not for subpages or subfolders.

I have seen this [how can I Redirect all requests to https and non-www in one jump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399266/how-can-i-redirect-all-requests-to-https-and-non-www-in-one-jump)
and tried to get a combination, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the requests with `https` and `www`, you want to check the requests whether they haven't `https` and `www` in the requests.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

- In the first Condition(`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]`), it is checking the `HTTP_HOST` has not (`!^www\.`) www. `[NC]` - Not Case sensitive `[OR]` logical `OR`ing next condition.
- The second condition (`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`) checks not present `https` in the `HTTP_HOST`.
- The third condition (`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]`), used to capture the rest part of the request if available.
- Finally (`RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]`), we are adding the `https` and the `www` with the request.

Comment: Hello Thanks,
but it doesn't work.
If I have for example 
- http://example.com/example/
- https://example.com/example/
there is no redirect to
- https://www.example.com/example/

That is still my problem

Comment: Did you write this on the top of the htaccess ?

Comment: Hello!
There are no changes depending on where I place it